# Proper way to define properties in a Javascript contructor

Tags: javascript

So I am new to javascript (coming from a strong java background) and I wanted to know the proper way to define properties or variables in a class or constructor.

```
function RootNode(sTitle, authName, storyNum){
    this.sTitle = sTitle; 
    this.authName = authName; 
    this.storyNum = storyNum;
    this.creationDate =  new Date();
}
```

or

```
function RootNode(sTitle, authName, storyNum){

    var sTitle = sTitle; 
    var authName = authName; 
    var storyNum = storyNum;
    var creationDate =  new Date();  
}
```

Comment: #1. In #2 you create local variables.

Comment: There are no classes in JavaScript (at least,  not yet).

Comment: And when there are, I wouldn't use them. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PSGEjv3Tqo0

Answer (score 3):

**Simple answer: use the first one**

---

**More detailed answer**

The first snippet sets the `sTitle`, `authName`, `storyNum`, and `creationDate` properties on the object.

The second snippet creates 4 local variables and sets their values. Those variables are inaccessible from outside the function.

You can use the local variables and the object variables together like this:

```
function RootNode(sTitle, authName, storyNum) {
    this.sTitle = sTitle; // you can access this variable when you . into the object

    var privateVariable = 'You cannot see this variable when you . into the object directly';
    this.methodInObject = function() {
        return privateVariable; // but you can access the variable from the function
    }
}
```

***Note:*** You probably want to add a `return this;` at the end of the constructor function so that it returns the object that you constructed.

***UPDATE:*** Per the comments, you do **not** have to `return this;` as using `new RootNode` does this automagically (+1 for using automagically? :))

---

**Further Reading**

- [Introduction to Object-Oriented JavaScript from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript)
- [Pseudo-Classical Pattern](http://javascript.info/tutorial/pseudo-classical-pattern)
- [JavaScript Inheritance: Pseudoclassical vs. Prototypal](http://theoryapp.com/javascript-inheritance-pseudoclassical-vs-prototypal/)

Comment: Returning `this` is unnecessary as `new` does that for you already.

Comment: @plalx thanks for pointing that out. I didn't know that (or if I learned that, I'd forgotten). I've been enlightened.

Comment: A constructor must return an object. If there isn't a return statement that does so, it will return the object referenced by *this*. Some like to use `return this` for clarity, though there are arguments not to (e.g. don't have a return then if *new* is omitted in the call the function will return *undefined* - break early and hard).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the first style, but I personally prefer this: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp

Comment: I think the OP is trying to use JS in a "pseudo-classical" manner.

Comment: @jsve what would a "pseudo-classical" manor be? Coming from a strong background in java and c is there a different approach I should be giving javascript in regards to view?

Comment: @crazyCoder here are a few references: http://theoryapp.com/javascript-inheritance-pseudoclassical-vs-prototypal/ and http://javascript.info/tutorial/pseudo-classical-pattern. Basically pseudo-classical JS makes JS behave like a classical language in some regards.

Answer (score 0):

The first way is correct.

```
function RootNode(sTitle, authName, storyNum) {
    this.sTitle = sTitle; 
    this.authName = authName; 
    this.storyNum = storyNum;
    this.creationDate = new Date();
}
```

However, this method isn't really like a class, its more of a unique object. Defining the object this way is more like a Java class.

```
function RootNode(sTitle, authName, storyNum) {
    //your constructor
    this.sTitle = sTitle; 
    this.authName = authName; 
    this.storyNum = storyNum;
    this.creationDate = new Date();
}

RootNode.prototype.myMethod = function() {
    //my code
}
```

This pattern is useful as it allows multiple instantiation without duplicating the memory for the properties. Also, it's necessary if you want to create sub classes. Read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype) to learn about the prototype and constructor properties

Comment: Why would `var RootNode = function` be any better than a straight function declaration? It's actually worse since the constructor is unnamed. With your proposed construct, `RootNode.name` will return empty string.

Comment: That's a good point. My focus was on prototype. I'll edit it.